# Data serialization on WIndows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter, datacontractserializer

I'm following [this tutorial](http://igrali.com/2012/06/17/twitter-authentication-from-windows-phone-app/) and I'm stuck at the part where the TwitterAcces class (that contains the twitter token) is serialized. This is where the serialization method is called:

```
    void CallBackVerifiedResponse(OAuthAccessToken at, TwitterResponse response)
    {
        if (at != null)
        {
            SerializeHelper.SaveSetting<TwitterAccess>("TwitterAccess", new TwitterAccess
            {
                AccessToken = at.Token,
                AccessTokenSecret = at.TokenSecret,
                ScreenName = at.ScreenName,
                UserId = at.UserId.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is my SerializeHelper.cs:

```
public class SerializeHelper
{
    public static void SaveSetting<T>(string fileName, T dataToSave)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = store.CreateFile(fileName))
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                    serializer.WriteObject(stream, dataToSave);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The error I'm getting is: `The type or namespace name 'DataContractSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Visual Studio can't help me resolve the problem. It suggests creating a new class. I googled around and I think the class should be inside `System.Runtime.Serialization;` which I am using but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you got `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` referenced within your project?

Comment: I have the `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` statement. Or should I add it to the project in some other way?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx - check 'To add a reference in Visual C# or Visual J#' section

Comment: Adding it as a reference fixed my error, thanks! Submit this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got to add `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` referenced in your project.